# Changing serial port settings with Gforth

Tags: serial-port, ffi, forth, gforth

I am trying to talk to a serial port (an Arduino device on `/dev/ttyUSB0`). I am running into trouble because to correctly read/write data, I need to set various parameters like speed and parity.

Is there a Gforth library that does this already?

I found this link which goes through and calls C functions to set termios parameters directly - http://www.forth.org/svfig/kk/TestSerial.f.txt, but I'd much prefer to use something that comes with Gforth itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a Gforth library that does this already?

Yes. Gforth interface words for Linux serial communcations:

https://github.com/earl/gforth-mirror/blob/master/contrib/serial.fs

Comment: LQP reviewers: Please VTC.